# How to show data in another database with codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I want to show data but the database is different with my setup database in, config/database. But when I run this code, it gives me error.

Here is my code:

```
public function Asset($param = "")
{
    $conn = array( "Database"=>"United2",
                        "UID"=>"it", 
                        "PWD"=>"uni");
    $import = sqlsrv_connect("10.11.1.6", $conn);

    $cols = array("Kode","Description","Keterangan");
    $idx = "Kode";
    $tbl = ("(
                SELECT Kode, Description, Keterangan FROM Ms_OtherAsset
            ) src    
            ", $import);
    $whr = "";
    $data = $this->GetDataMsSQL($cols,$idx,$tbl,$whr);
    $output = $data["output"];
    $datares = $data["datares"];
    if(!empty($datares))
    {
        foreach($datares->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $r = array();
            foreach($cols as $c)
            {    
                $r[] = $row[$c];
            }
            $output["aaData"][] = $r;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Comment: and what would the error be?

Comment: @smith it give me " DataTables warning: table id=tblData - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1" because i use datatable. I think my query is wrong when i added $import, because when i'm not using another database it is not error

Comment: check your output to see if you are getting valid JSON by printing it.

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy i think i'm wrong with this code $tbl = ("(
                SELECT Kode, Description, Keterangan FROM Ms_OtherAsset
            ) src    
            ", $import);

Comment: The problem is with your JSON. It seems it could be incomplete.

Comment: @hungrykoala yess because my query is wrong, $tbl =( "(
                SELECT Kode, Description, Keterangan FROM Ms_OtherAsset
            ) src    
            ", $import);

Comment: You also need a few more parameters for your JSON so that Datatables can process it accordingly.

Comment: first check if your query is returning any result or not.

Comment: Check [this](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) for the valid json format for datatables. It's in the `Example data` section

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy there's any result in my query. my query is not wrong. but i dont know how to use $data = $this->GetDataMsSQL($cols,$idx,$tbl,$whr);

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple database connection group in codeigniter with different group name.

```
    $db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
    $db['default']['username'] = "root";
    $db['default']['password'] = "";
    $db['default']['database'] = "database_name";
    $db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
    $db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
    $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
    $db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
    $db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
    $db['default']['swap_pre'] = "";
    $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

    $db['otherdb']['hostname'] = "localhost";
    $db['otherdb']['username'] = "root";
    $db['otherdb']['password'] = "";
    $db['otherdb']['database'] = "other_database_name";
    $db['otherdb']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
    $db['otherdb']['dbprefix'] = "";
    $db['otherdb']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db['otherdb']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
    $db['otherdb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['otherdb']['cachedir'] = "";
    $db['otherdb']['char_set'] = "utf8";
    $db['otherdb']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
    $db['otherdb']['swap_pre'] = "";
    $db['otherdb']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['otherdb']['stricton'] = FALSE;

$CI = & get_instance();
$CI->db = $this->load->database('otherdb', true);
```

Comment: here is my setup config/database https://pastebin.com/B1WGaa5U . But it give me "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\svn\tes\application\config\database.php on line 84"

Comment: $CI = & get_instance();
$CI->db = $this->load->database('otherdb', true);

use this code in model. Use it before connecting to the database..

Comment: it still give me error, have a look my code https://pastebin.com/JPabdsLz

Answer (score 0):

```
**Use this db config code:**

$db_name = 'test_db_name';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_password = '123456';
$config['dsn'] = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db_name";
$config['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['username'] = "$db_user";
$config['password'] = "$db_password";
$config['database'] = "$db_name";
$config['dbdriver'] = "pdo";
$config['dbprefix'] = "";
$config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$this->db1 = $this->load->database($config, TRUE);
```